# How to scan a range of IP addresses on a specific port

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm trying to figure out how to scan a specific TCP port within a range of IPaddresses?

This is my code so far:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IPAddress beginIP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.1");
    IPAddress EndIP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.3.3");
    int PortNumber = 80;

    bool portStatu = scanPort(BeginIP,EndIP,PortNumber);
}

public bool scanPort(IPAddress beginIP,IPAddress endIP , int portNumber)
{
     //What should i write...
}
```

Comment: Just connect to it. If you can connect, it's open, else it's closed

Comment: as @sLowDowN wrote. Try tp connect to the IP at the given port and see if you're able to connect or not. You just have to iterate through the ip range and output the state.

Comment: Which part is the actual problem? Iterating the addresses or scaning the port?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [TcpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx) Class to check your ports, and run this in parallel in an `async` / `await` pattern (suitable for IO bound operations) using [ActionBlock Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194684(v=vs.110).aspx) in the [TPL dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library) library.

**You can generate your ips like this**

```
public static List<IPAddress> GenerateIPAddressList(string fromIP, string toIp)
{
   var start = IPAddress.Parse(fromIP).GetAddressBytes();
   var end = IPAddress.Parse(toIp).GetAddressBytes();
   var addresses = new List<IPAddress>();
   for (var i = start[0]; i <= end[0]; i++)
      for (var j = start[1]; j <= end[1]; j++)
         for (var k = start[2]; k <= end[2]; k++)
            for (var l = start[2]; l <= end[3]; l++)
               addresses.Add(new IPAddress(new[] { i, j, k, l }));
   return addresses;
}
```

[**Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gMKj9u)

---

To get this working in an `async` *Parallel* and *IO* suitable away, first create your worker method

**Main Method**

```
private static readonly List<Tuple<IPAddress,int>> _passed = new List<Tuple<IPAddress, int>>();
private static readonly List<Tuple<IPAddress, int, int>> _failed = new List<Tuple<IPAddress, int, int>>();
private static readonly object _sync = new object();

 ...

public static async Task TestSocket(IPAddress ip)
{
   try
   {
      Console.WriteLine("testing : " + ip);
      // create a socket
      using (var tcpClient = new TcpClient())
      {
         // connect in an async fashion
         await tcpClient.ConnectAsync(ip, 80);
         lock (_sync)
            _passed.Add(new Tuple<IPAddress, int>(ip, 80));
      }
   }
   catch (SocketException ex)
   {
      // if we failed work out why
      lock (_sync)
         _failed.Add(new Tuple<IPAddress, int,  int>(ip, 80, ex.ErrorCode));
   }
}
```

**DataFlow**

```
public static async Task DoWorkLoads(List<IPAddress> addresses)
{
   var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
                     {
                        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 50
                     };

   var block = new ActionBlock<IPAddress>(TestSocket, options);

   foreach (var ip in addresses)
      block.Post(ip);

   block.Complete();
   await block.Completion;

}
```

**Usage**

```
public static void Main()
{

   // create some ip addresses that might work
   var list = GenerateIPAddressList("192.168.1.1","192.168.1.5");

   // start the work load
   DoWorkLoads(list).Wait();

   // out put the results
   Console.WriteLine("passed");
   Console.WriteLine("--------");

   foreach (var result in _passed)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(result.Item1 + " : " + result.Item2);
   }

   Console.WriteLine();
   Console.WriteLine("failed");
   Console.WriteLine("--------");
   foreach (var result in _failed)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(result.Item1 + " : " + result.Item2 + " : error code = " + result.Item3);
   }
}
```

**Output**

```
passed
--------
127.0.0.1 : 80
1.1.1.1 : 80
87.106.238.190 : 80

failed
--------
255.70.6.101 : 80 : error code = 10051
8.8.8.8 : 80 : error code = 10060
132.159.217.202 : 80 : error code = 10060
63.14.47.133 : 80 : error code = 10060
99.5.58.81 : 80 : error code = 10060
164.105.83.243 : 80 : error code = 10060
28.162.4.38 : 80 : error code = 10060
45.255.42.252 : 80 : error code = 10060
189.71.3.147 : 80 : error code = 10060
61.77.87.169 : 80 : error code = 10060
```

---

Id usually give a working  demo here, however `TcpClient` is forbidden on .net Fiddle

Though you can see a similar [**Dataflow Ping Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zp4FEB) i wrote